# Can't play video on liferay portal

Tags: video, portlet, liferay-6

In liferay portal I've placed Media portlet and referenced it to folder with some video. But there is problem with playing video on portlet itself. 
At the beginning, I thought it's because of video file has wrong reference. But if I download it, it plays without any problem.

link to portal: [kazagro.kz](http://www.kazagro.kz/en/web/ka-onim/videos?p_p_id=31&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_pos=3&p_p_col_count=4&_31__20_folderId=107647&_31__20_struts_action=/document_library/view&_31__20_viewFolders=false&_31__20_folderEnd=20&_31__20_displayStyle=icon&_31__20_folderStart=0&_31__20_entryStart=0&_31__20_viewEntries=1&_31__20_entryEnd=20)

Answer (score 0):

Hi may be problem with vedio extensions..

Login as Admin in the server Administration you can external Services.there you can

Enabling Xuggler provides video conversion functionality.

this may be help you if enable this..

Try some other video formats....

Please have a look into [LiferaySavvy.com](http://LiferaySavvy.com) for more liferay Stuff

Comment: I've tried different extensions. It doesn't depend on formats.